# Any other Linux application similar to Greyhole?

Tags: linux

Is there any other Linux application similar to [Greyhole](http://www.greyhole.net/)? Preferably without relying on samba? I'm going to use it for a typical home server. The features that I want are what Greyhole has (from the link):

- JBOD concatenation storage pool
- Easily recoverable files

I already tried LVM and RAID, but the drives aren't readable on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found what I was looking for: [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/)

Basically, it combines several branches (mount points like /mnt/hd1, /mnt/hd2 etc.) into a single tree (/mnt/virtual). The filesystem in each of the mount points doesn't matter, AUFS will merge all the same. This also means that the mount points are readable on their own. Also, AUFS can balance free space and it's exportable using NFS or Samba.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, Greyhole can use any filesystem also.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no such alternatives.

Some people have suggested writing a logger for Greyhole that would use FUSE or something else, to replace logs created by Samba, but nobody ever contributed code that would do that.

Most people who need local access to files mount their (Greyhole) Samba shares locally, and point to that in the various programs that need to access the files protected/spread by Greyhole. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

BTRFS is stable enough to provide a good solution to storage pooling and snapshot backup.

Comment: Can it support different drive sizes with redundancy?

Comment: @Frank Last I heard, BTRFS doesn't have a fsck utility.